# Didn't defined variable in javascript but code is still working why?

Tags: javascript, operators

in this i didn't defined now variable but when i run code in console it is working why?

```js
var year, yearJohn, yearMark;
now = 2018
year = 2018;
yearJohn = year - 28;
yearMark = year - 33;
console.log(yearJohn, yearMark);
console.log(now + 2);
```

i expect the output of code will be syntax error, but the actual outpur is 2020.

Comment: Those variables get defined in the current context. It is similar to debugging JS code where you can add new variables. Like you defined now as 2018 and added 2 so the output is 2020

Comment: You have `now = 2018`, and in non-strict mode, variable assignments with no prior declaration will automatically cause said variable to be added to the global context. Running the code in strict-mode will cause a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: You don't have to manually add each line with with *"enter code here"*. Please read: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186) and [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0):

See [MDN documentation for *var*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

> Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a global variable (it becomes a property of the global object) when the assignment is executed.